# jquery getjson function: Call back returns wrong string

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, getjson, countdown

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin for countdown. (I use a php framework also). this is my script in main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get(baseUrl + "/countdown", {id: "609|610|611|612"}, function (data) {
        auctions = data.split("||");
        for (n = 0; n < auctions.length; n++) {
            if (auctions[n] != undefined) {
                divis = auctions[n].split("##");
                if (divis[1] != "stop") {
                    $('#bid' + divis[0]).countdown(divis[1], function (event) {
                        var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
                        $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours + ' hr %M min %S sec'));
                    });

                } else {
                    $('#bid' + divis[0]).html("closed");
                }

            }
        }
    });
});
```

the "countdown" is a php file which returns this string:

```
609##stop||610##stop||611##2016/03/28 13:00:56||612##2016/04/03 01:00:00||
```

using this, causes me too many errors. if i change "auctions.length" to "4" everything become ok and right! i checked the value of "data", instead of the exact string returned by "countdown.php", it is bigger and containes some spaces! I also checked "auctions.length" value and it's 7!
I don't know why this happens.

also when i ghange $.get to $.getJSON no countdown is shown. why is that?

thank for your attention:)
and thank you for your tolerance for my English mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Because your response data is not in JSON format, so $.getJSON got nothing, I suggest you use JSON format for response.

in PHP

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => '609',
        'datetime' => 'stop'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '610',
        'datetime' => 'stop'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '611',
        'datetime' => '2016/03/28 13:00:56'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '612',
        'datetime' => '2016/04/03 01:00:00'
    )
);
echo(json_encode($data));
```

and in JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(baseUrl + "/countdown", {id: "609|610|611|612"}, function (auctions) {
        for (n = 0; n < auctions.length; n++) {
            if (auctions[n] != undefined) {
                divis = auctions[n];
                if (divis.datetime != "stop") {
                    $('#bid' + divis.id).countdown(divis.datetime, function (event) {
                        var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
                        $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours + ' hr %M min %S sec'));
                    });

                } else {
                    $('#bid' + divis.id).html("closed");
                }

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the Content-Type response header when you are outputting something other than HTML. PHP defaults to claiming all output is HTML.

Comment: @Learning: thanks but it did not work.still with getJSON I get no countdown. The funny point is when I add console.log(data); -when I use get()- this is what console shows me:609##stop||610##stop||611##2016/03/15 20:20:56||612##2016/04/03 01:00:00||<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">.....</body><!--Body Close--></html>     It attaches the whole html to "data"!